# C++: Making a global ofstream variable

Tags: c++, extern, ofstream

I want to open an output file in `main.cpp`, then write to it in another file `calculate.cpp`.

**main.cpp**:

```
#include main.hpp

using namespace std;

int main() {
    outputfile.open("output.txt");
}
```

using the global variable from the header file `main.hpp`

```
extern std::ofstream outputfile;
```

Then write to it in another file **calculate.cpp**

```
#include main.hpp

void calculate() {
    outputfile << "write this to the external file" << endl;
}
```

When I do this, I get the error

```
undefined reference to 'outputfile' in main.cpp
undefined reference to 'outputfile' in calculate.cpp
```

I'm working on a large code that has a premade make file, so I don't think proper linking is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined `outputfile` anywhere. The line `extern std::ofstream outputfile;` declares the variable, but nothing actually defines storage for it. You need the following line in either `main.cpp` or `calculate.cpp`

```
std::ofstream outputfile;
```

Comment: `Clang-Tidy: Initialization of 'outputfile' with static storage duration may throw an exception that cannot be caught`